# Accessing Span Elements

Tags: web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

When trying to scrape out the integer value for movie reviews from IMDB reviews , i am confused on how to access the rating when its inspect html  is just listed as, 10, and changes for each individual rating (i.e 7 . How would I use the soup.find_all to access these values and add them to a list- i am confused how to do this when there is no class listed for the variable?

```
rate=soup.find_all('span')
rate_list=[]
for i in range(0,len(rate)):
    rate_list.append(rate[i].get_text())
```

Comment: Are the ratings generated dynamically on the page? Can you share the link of the exact page you're trying to scrape?

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/reviews?ref_=tt_urv%27

Answer (score 0):

Try using the fact the target span sits next to the star

```
ratings = [i.text for i in soup.select('.ipl-star-icon + span')]
```

But, in case there are ratings for everything I would probably loop reviews (`for review in soup.select('.lister-item-content):` .....) and test if `review.select_one('.ipl-star-icon + span') is not None`